# Is it possible to "lock" Firefox in one state and run it from that state?

Tags: firefox

Is this possible? For example to do something like "hibernate" for Firefox, that is to run it wit all plugins in a certain state.

Answer (score 0):

You can PAUSE the process with:

```
kill -STOP $( pidof firefox )
```

and return with:

```
kill -CONT $( pidof firefox )
```

Or use the `gnome-system-monitor`:

[image]

Comment: And will it continue after a reboot?

Comment: Only if you use hibernate to power down your system.